# Java: count occurrences in 2d array and output result in 1d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm start to learn Java programming language and  try to solve given task

I'm try to finish method to count occurrences in 2d array and output result in 1d

```
public static int[] histogram(int[][] a, int high) {
    // Please write your code after this line
    // init new array 
    int numOfRows = a.length;
    int numOfCols = a[0].length;
    int[] retVal = {};
    //main loop
    for (int o = 0; o < high; o++){
        //System.out.println(o);
        // go trough rows 
        for(int row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++ ){
            // check for colum values
            int count = 0;
            for(int col = 0; col < numOfCols; col++ ){

                if(a[row][col] = o ){
                    count++;
                }

            }
            retVal[o] = count; // Fixed typo 

        }


    }


    return retVal;
}
```

this is my method

I'm using BlueJ IDE for compiling and when i compile i get error 
"Incompatible types " for this line

if(a[row][col] = o )

i don't get it why i get error, in my opininon a[row][col] is int type ?
and o is int type too.

Thanks

Comment: Can I suggest that `o` is a not a good choice of variable name? It looks far too much like `0` at a glance (in certain fonts).

Comment: thanks for suggestion this is anyway all not finished i'll keep your suggestion on my mind for final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(a[row][col] = o ) // Assignment Operator
```

should be

```
if(a[row][col] == o ) // Equality evaluator
```

[**Operators JavaDoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a[row][col] = o )
```

use == operator for checking equality, so finally it should be

```
if(a[row][col] == o )
```

Comment: uhm. i that is it, i constantly think about operators and i miss this :(

Comment: @SileCetoy : always remember that == results in boolean